# How to dynamically set text in a google forms form?

Tags: google-forms

My google form will be accessed behind a logged in web form.  I would like to set text (or an answer that is r/o) to personalize the experience based on login information.  I know how to prefill an answer using "get pre-filled link", but I cannot determine how to set text dynamically.

I have tried using prefilled questions, but they allow the user to edit.  I don't want the information that I am prefilling to be editable.

Answer (score 0):

`How to dynamically set text in a google forms form?`, `personalize the experience based on login information`, `but I cannot determine how to set text dynamically`

Google Forms does NOT provide the feature of dynamic data updates.